# Android программное изменение системных настроек смартфона

Tags: android

Как программным путём изменять режим "Без звука", "Мобильный интернет", "Режим полёт", "Экономия энергии", например: 
включить режим без звука, выключить интернет и т.д.

Answer (score 5):

Режим без звука:

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
```

Отключить `Wifi`:

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
```

`3G`:

```
public void mobileDataEnable(boolean enabled) {
    try { 
        final ConnectivityManager conman = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        final Class<?> conmanClass = Class.forName(conman.getClass().getName());
        final Field iConnectivityManagerField = conmanClass.getDeclaredField("mService");
        iConnectivityManagerField.setAccessible(true);
        final Object iConnectivityManager = iConnectivityManagerField.get(conman);
        final Class<?> iConnectivityManagerClass = Class.forName(iConnectivityManager.getClass().getName());
        final Method setMobileDataEnabledMethod = iConnectivityManagerClass.getDeclaredMethod("setMobileDataEnabled", Boolean.TYPE);
        setMobileDataEnabledMethod.setAccessible(true);
        setMobileDataEnabledMethod.invoke(iConnectivityManager, enabled);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }     
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за режим без звука. Мне нужен моб. инет(3g, 4g), а не вайфай

Comment: ещё нужно добавить пермишены для включения/выключения режима без звука, вот [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43123650/android-request-access-notification-policy-and-mute-phone/43127589)

Comment: обновил ответ...

Comment: у меня этот код не работает, ошибка на |||  final Method setMobileDataEnabledMethod = iConnectivityManagerClass.getDeclaredMethod("setMobileDataEnabled", Boolean.TYPE);  ||| пишет, точно не помню что, но похоже на то, что метод не найден или не корректный

Comment: вот собственно сам текст ошибки "java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: setMobileDataEnabled [boolean]"